# iperf3 results should look nice in a logfile

Tags: logs, text-formatting

I have this result:

```
Wed Aug 15 19:35:11 CEST 2018
Connecting to host x.x.x.x, port 5201
[  4] local x.x.x.x port 48944 connected to x.x.x.x port 5201
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth       Retr  Cwnd
[  4]   0.00-1.00   sec   375 MBytes  3.14 Gbits/sec  273    471 KBytes
[  4]   1.00-2.00   sec   428 MBytes  3.59 Gbits/sec  145    376 KBytes
[  4]   2.00-3.00   sec   360 MBytes  3.02 Gbits/sec  148    454 KBytes
[  4]   3.00-4.00   sec   339 MBytes  2.84 Gbits/sec   83    407 KBytes
[  4]   4.00-5.00   sec   305 MBytes  2.56 Gbits/sec  104    414 KBytes
[  4]   5.00-6.00   sec   301 MBytes  2.53 Gbits/sec  186    440 KBytes
[  4]   6.00-7.00   sec   325 MBytes  2.73 Gbits/sec  174    485 KBytes
[  4]   7.00-8.00   sec   434 MBytes  3.64 Gbits/sec   81    677 KBytes
[  4]   8.00-9.00   sec   412 MBytes  3.46 Gbits/sec  226    537 KBytes
[  4]   9.00-10.00  sec   409 MBytes  3.43 Gbits/sec   47    372 KBytes
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth       Retr
[  4]   0.00-10.00  sec  3.60 GBytes  3.09 Gbits/sec  1467             sender
[  4]   0.00-10.00  sec  3.60 GBytes  3.09 Gbits/sec                      receiver
```

And I just want one line like this :-)

```
17-08-15 19:35:11 0.00-10.00  sec  3.60 GBytes  3.09 Gbits/sec  1467
```

How is that possible?

I have begun the script like this, but I think I should use awk, cut etc.

```
host=x.x.x.x
log=/data/div/sh/iperf.log
logr=reverseiperf.log
runs=2

for run in $(seq 1 $runs); do
    date >> $log && iperf3 -c $host >> $log
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the slimmest way to do this but hopefully shows you "one way" to do it:

```
$ printf "%s%s\n" \
   "$(TZ=CEST date -d "$(head -1 iperf.txt)" "+%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")" \
   "$(grep sender iperf.txt | awk -F"]  " '{print $2}')"
18-08-15 19:35:11 0.00-10.00  sec  3.60 GBytes  3.09 Gbits/sec  1467             sender
```

This works as follows:

- `printf "%s%s\n"` - prints 2 strings that we're going to parse from your `iperf.txt` output
- `"$(TZ=CEST date -d "$(head -1 iperf.txt)" "+%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")"` - parses the 1st line from `iperf.txt` (`head -1`) and passes that to the `date` command, and reformats the date in the format you're example shows
- `"$(grep sender iperf.txt | awk -F"]  " '{print $2}')"` - parses the line that contains the string `sender`, and then splits this line on the characters `]`, printing the right side of the `]` arguments that were split. This result is the `$2`.

Comment: Yes, it works.
So first I'm running the script that pipes output to a temporary file, i the same script I'am using the lines above that pipes the line to the logfile :-)
Thanks.